# Conditional MDX QUERY

Tags: mdx

I have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02OKu.png):

the first table is how my data looks like and the second table is how my query should show the result
dimensions :

> Service , Company

Measure :

> Amount

there are **two records** (with amount) for each **Service** in my fact table, one for **mainCompany** and the other one for **one of the other companies** (like Service1 for MainCompany And Company1)

each company can have more than one service

each service has just 2 record and one of them is for maincompany

I want to have Amount of maincompany to display as a measure for other companies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[AmountMainCompany] as
SUM(
    [Service].[Service].[Service].Members,
    IIF(
        [Measures].[Amount] > 0,
        ([Company].[Company].[MainCompany],[Measures].[Amount]),
        Null
    )

)

Select 
[Measures].[AmountMainCompany] on 0,
Non Empty {[Company].[Company].[Company].Members - [Company].[Company].[MainCompany]} on 1
from [MyCube]
```

**AmountMainCompany** measure checks if the current service contains a *Amount* value. If so, it aggregates the **MainCompany** member *Amount* value.

Comment: GREATE !!!! Thank u very much , I just add **,null)**  at the end of 7th line and it worked @};-

Comment: just one more thing, when I create a CalculatedMeasure with this formula, it works with **Company** dimension well , but not with **Company and service toghether** , I mean it repeat the sum of amount for all services belongs to each company for all services :( is there a way to make that works too ?

Comment: Try the existing keyword before [Service].[Service].[Service].Members.

Comment: I faced another problem when checking the result , every thing is OK for data like what I showed in picture , but there are some services that has Amount=0 for the company but Amount=[value] for mainCompany , so beacuse we used **[Measures].[Amount] > 0** it doesn't show anything for that company, is there a way to distinguish between 0 and nothing ?

Comment: Try [Measures].[Amount] >= 0 ?

Comment: I did, it doesn't work, it will return same value for all companies, in fact it shows the some of all mainCompany values for all the companies

Comment: I Used : IIF(
        ISEMPTY([Measures].[Amount]),Null,
        ([Company].[Company].[MainCompany],[Measures].[Amount])
    )

Comment: In sake of performance you may use: IIF([Measures].[Amount], ([Company].[Company].[MainCompany],[Measures].[Amount]),Null)